# write multiple excel files with xlsxwriter python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

is there a way to create multi excel files with xlsxwriter?

```
from itertools import chain
import glob ,csv, sys, os

openSoundingFile = 'D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding2/*.txt'


for filename in glob.glob(openSoundingFile):
    newName = filename
    spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=';',quotechar='"')
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding2/' + newName[:-4] + '.xlsx'
    sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Original data')

    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowx, colx, value)


    workbook.close()
```

so i wanna to save all the txt files to exel files. I think the problem is here

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding2/' + newName[:-4] + '.xlsx'
```

if i'm not using  `+ newName[:-4] +` it will work but only write 1 excel files. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What happens when you run the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error showed that you combined the path to the files 2 times on top of each other:

```
'D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding2/bla.txtD:/apera/Workspace/Sounding2/'
```

This does it for me:

```
import xlsxwriter
import glob ,csv

openSoundingFile = 'D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding2/*.txt'

for filename in glob.glob(openSoundingFile):
    spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=';',quotechar='"')
    # Note that filename is the full path already! Just [:-4] to remove .txt
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename[:-4] + '.xlsx')
    sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Original data')
    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowx, colx, value)
    workbook.close()
```